# Trying to understand the javascript event loop: Why do effects occur simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know that in the following html + javascript/jquery code, the three items will all fade in simultaneously. What I don't really know is why.

```
<ul>
<li id='foo'></li>
<li id='bar'></li>
<li id='baz'></li>       
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#foo').text('foo').hide().fadeIn(5000);
$('#bar').text('bar').hide().fadeIn(5000);
$('#baz').text('baz').hide().fadeIn(5000);
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jengzz9g/

My understanding is that each fadeIn effect would get added to the event loop FIFO queue. But don't all events in this queue get handled synchronously and each event handler runs to completion until the next in the queue is called? If so, shouldn't each fadeIn effect happen one at a time? Obviously, this is not what is happening (and it wouldn't be good if it did).

Instead is something like this happening? foo fades in for 16ms (assuming 60hz repainting) and then the handler calls itself thus putting itself back on the queue; then bar fades in for 16ms, then its handler calls itself; then baz fades in and its handler calls itself. This cycle continues for 5000ms.

Something like this would make sense, but I am just guessing and would like to know for sure how it works.

Comment: it has more to do with the way jquery works, as I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why?**

`setTimeout` and `setInterval` are **asynchronous** operations... The fadeIn function supplied by jquery uses the setTimeout function to move the animation along one frame... then allows the rest of the code to try and move on a bit, and then it gets called again to progress the frame a little more.

**Example code to explain:**

Imagine this:

```
var currentAnimationFrame = 0;

function AnimateABit()
{
    currentAnimationFrame++;

    if( currentAnimationFrame < 10 )
    {
        setTimeout( function(){
            AnimateABit();
        }, 1000 );        
    }
}

function fadeIn()
{
    AnimateABit();
}

fadeIn();
```

Imagine the above code is how jquery works.

It might declare a global variable to keep track of which frame we are on, we then call `fadeIn()` which calls the `AnimateABit` function... increases the animation frame by 1, then tells the code to wait 1000 (1 second) and then run the `AnimateABit` function again...

While the wait 1000 part is called, the rest of the code is allowed to resume (asynchronous).

**How?**

Usually, this asynchronous ability is due to firing off new processor threads which means code can run simultaneously... *unfortunately Javascript isn't quite that clever but it does get the job done in some convoluted way which i forget how it works :)*

**Solution to your problem**

jquery gives you a way of signalling when the animation code has completed (a call back function), it works like this:

```
$().fadeIn( 5000, function() {
    // The animation has finished, now let's do the next bit:
    $().fadeIn( 5000, function() {
        // And so on...
    } );
});
```

**Future read:**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700330.aspx

Be mindful of ajax calls as well, these too are asynchronous.

Comment: As I remembered correctly, the browser will try to execute `setTimeout` and other similar asycn functions at the right moment. If there are lines that are still running, the browser will wait for those to complete before executing the async functions.

Answer (score 0):

Because all javascript code are synchronous except like setTimeout function.

If you want to run your code one after another then you should pass a callback like below:

```
$('#foo').text('foo').hide().fadeIn(5000,function(){
   $('#bar').text('bar').hide().fadeIn(5000,function(){
      $('#baz').text('baz').hide().fadeIn(5000);
   });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jengzz9g/1/)

Comment: I appreciate that callbacks are necessary to create the sequence of effects. My question is why, if javascript is all synchronous and runs on one thread, the three effects occur simultaneously. If the effects were asynchronous, then the callbacks would make perfect sense.

Comment: @mjandrews The registering part is synchronous, however the animation part is asynchronous.

Comment: @mjandrews - By the way, if you want to make them appear one by one, you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/jengzz9g/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delay()` to offset each animation. `delay()` will get put into each elements `animation queue`.

```
var duration = 2000;

$.each(['foo','bar','baz'], function(i, item){
    $('#'+item).text(item).hide().delay( i * duration).fadeIn(duration)
});
```

Reference: [delay() docs](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jo4tdv6y/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to relatively easily analyse how it's working (step by step), I would advise to you to use Timeline from Chrome DevTools, which is pretty handy tool to this kind of stuff.[image]

Last, but not least, Philip Roberts gave a great [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) at JSConf EU, which gives a deep understanding on how the event loop works, which you might find useful to solve you issue.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Or from IE11 Dev tools... which are imo slightly easier to read :)

Answer (score 0):

> *"I know that in the following html + javascript/jquery code, the three items will all fade in simultaneously. What I don't really know is why."*

Cause you started all three animations simultaneously:

```
#foo >> start with your stuff
#bar >> start with your stuff
#baz >> start with your stuff
```

it's like your expecting `title` and `fooBar` to be executed after some animations:

```
$('#foo').fadeIn(10000);
// Nope, JS is syncronous and we don't wait for jQuery animations :)
$("#title").text("TITLE"); //< "I'm not going to wait 10000ms sir!"
function fooBar(){
   // other important code here
}
fooBar(); //< "I have no time too :)"
```

jQuery people knew that one would like to *Do this and Do that* once an animation ends, therefore most animating Methods like `.animate()`, `fadeTo()`, `fadeIn()`, `fadeToggle()` etc. have an argument called:

### callback

```
/* fadeIn example: */    .fadeIn([time] [, callback])
```

where once jQuery finishes the animation will trigger whatever function you use as **callback**:

```
$("#foo").fadeIn(10000, function(){
   // do something after 10s
});
```

Another solution is to use the jQuery's `.delay()` method, which is than stack in the current `animation.queue` bound to your element:

```
$("#foo").hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
```

and does:

- Set `STYLE display:none` to `#foo`
- add a `delay` of 1000ms to animation queue
- append a `fadeIn` to animation queue

For multiple elements you can get their index number (0,1,2...) and multiply that number by the desired delay time:

```
$("#foo, #bar, #baz").hide().each(function(idx, el){
   $(el).delay(idx*700).fadeIn(1000);
});
// All effects above will start at the same time, 
// the only difference is the increased `.delay(index*time)`
// bound to every element animation queue
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's pretty much as you've described it. There's a FIFO queue of JS functions that get executed in a synchronous, blocking fashion.

For your specific case of animations, they appear to run simultaneously because each animation is split into steps that are then interleaved with each other with the use of setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame.